# Can Cypress record audio from tests to also play it in the produced video?

Tags: audio, cypress

Is it possible to record audio from a website under test using Cypress, such that it is audible in the video recorded by Cypress? For example, the audio might come from an audio tag or a YouTube video.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,  you can use this if you want to ensure audio is playing for the client....if you're using audio or video elements.

```
const expectPlayingAudio = () => {
  cy.get('audio,video').should((els)=>{
    let audible = false
    els.each((i, el)=>{
      console.log(el)
      console.log(el.duration, el.paused, el.muted)
      if (el.duration > 0 && !el.paused && !el.muted) {
        audible = true
      }

      // expect(el.duration > 0 && !el.paused && !el.muted).to.eq(false)
    })
    expect(audible).to.eq(true)
  })
}

describe('page', () => {
  it('works', () => {
    cy.visit('/')
    expectPlayingAudio()
  })
})
```

Comment: For more in-depth knowledge see this thread [cypress audio and video tetsing](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/1750) here

Comment: Unfortunately this wont work, the client specifically wants a video produced by cypress with the audio in it.

Comment: I believe this is not possible yet

Comment: @Minok do you know if this is possible yet? I have a use case for this too. I can hear my `<audio>` playing when I run in headed mode. When I run in headless mode I also (strangely) hear it playing. But when I open the recorded .mp4 file, there is no audio recorded.